# Can't use text-overflow:ellipsis correctly

Tags: html, css

I want the text to "complete" the height length and when it reaches the maximum, it will use the ellipsis, but I can't figure it out. What I have only writes in a line and I wanted the full length

```html
<p class="download-text wow fadeInLeft" style="text-align:justify;height:100px;text-overflow:ellipsis;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus, elit ut blandit lacinia, magna ligula varius mi, in ultrices risus elit ac sem. In finibus tincidunt ligula, ut semper ante feugiat vitae. Phasellus consequat rutrum nulla in rhoncus.
  Fusce turpis magna, imperdiet ac massa eu, maximus porttitor ex. Nam vulputate ex id commodo pharetra. Nunc eget lectus ac nisi vestibulum congue. Donec eget diam nisl. Nulla massa est, efficitur eu enim at, imperdiet bibendum lorem. Duis iaculis felis
  id ex mattis, eu iaculis elit ullamcorper. Mauris semper fermentum justo sodales convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  <h6><button class="btn btn-default">See More</button></h6>
```

[image]

***UPDATE***

[image]

Removed the white-space:nowrap; but the ellipsis still don't appear

Comment: It is unclear what you ask, sorry. What is the difference in your eyes between "a line" and "the full length" ?

Comment: @arkascha I wanted the text to go till the See More button

Comment: Take away your `whitespace-nowrap`

Comment: This definitely works - https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: There is no pure `css` solution for this. The `text-overflow` rule only effects single line text passages.

Answer (score 0):

```css
p{
        overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -moz-box !important;
    line-height: 16px;
    max-height: 3.6rem;
    -moz-line-clamp: 3;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
}
```

```html
<p class="download-text wow fadeInLeft">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut faucibus, elit ut blandit lacinia, magna ligula varius mi, in ultrices risus elit ac sem. In finibus tincidunt ligula, ut semper ante feugiat vitae. Phasellus consequat rutrum nulla in rhoncus. Fusce turpis magna, imperdiet ac massa eu, maximus porttitor ex. Nam vulputate ex id commodo pharetra. Nunc eget lectus ac nisi vestibulum congue. Donec eget diam nisl. Nulla massa est, efficitur eu enim at, imperdiet bibendum lorem. Duis iaculis felis id ex mattis, eu iaculis elit ullamcorper. Mauris semper fermentum justo sodales convallis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<button class="btn btn-default">See More</button>
```

Comment: This does not result in an ellipsis getting applied.

Comment: @arkascha Now check it.